# How to retrieve data from 2 different where?

Tags: mysql, sql

I don't know how to word the title properly, anyway what I mean is:
For example I have this 'transaction' table

[image]

```
SELECT ITEM_ID, SUM(QUANTITY) AS IN
WHERE TYPE = IN
GROUP BY ITEM_ID
-
SELECT ITEM_ID, SUM(QUANTITY) AS OUT
WHERE TYPE = OUT
GROUP BY ITEM_ID
```

How do I combine those 2 statements so I can do operation on them?
Thanks
Basically what I want is something like this

```
SELECT ITEM_ID, 
SUM(QUANTITY) where Type = In "Item In", 
SUM(Quantity) where Type = Out "Item Out", 
Item In - Item Out "Final Qty"
GROUP BY ITEM_ID
```

Comment: edit: for some reason the table doesn't load in the final question. So I put a picture isntead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a subquery that pivots your rows into columns then `SELECT` from your subquery to find the difference:

```
SELECT a.ITEM_ID, 
       a.`Item In`, 
       a.`Item Out`, 
      (a.`Item In` - a.`Item Out`) AS `Final Qty`
FROM
(SELECT 
    ITEM_ID, 
    SUM( IF( TYPE = 'IN', QUANTITY, 0 ) ) AS `Item In`,  
    SUM( IF( TYPE = 'OUT', QUANTITY, 0 ) ) AS `Item Out`
  FROM 
    sample_table 
GROUP BY 
    ITEM_ID) a
```

**Result:**

| ITEM_ID | Item In | Item Out | Final Qty |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| X1 | 10 | 3 | 7 |
| X2 | 12 | 2 | 10 |

db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/R25liKWB).

Comment: thanks, I tried it and it works fine. If you don't mind me asking any idea how to use this statement on Laravel Query Builder or Eloquent?

Comment: I’m not sure, looking at the documentation [here](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queries) it seems possible. Your question was only around MySQL so what I would do is: [Accept an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) here in your question thread that works the best for you then take that answer/query and pose a new question with it, tagging Laravel in it. That way you’ll get people who are familiar with Laravel to provide you with an answer. Make sure you make an attempt prior to posing the question and explain what you did try.

Answer (score 1):

How about this

```
SELECT 
    ITEM_ID, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN TYPE=IN THEN QUANTITY else 0) AS IN_QUANTITY, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN TYPE=OUT THEN QUANTITY else 0) AS OUT_QUANTITY
WHERE TYPE IN [OUT,IN]
GROUP BY ITEM_ID
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use IN clause

```
SELECT ITEM_ID, SUM(QUANTITY) AS QUANTITY
WHERE TYPE IN [OUT,IN]
GROUP BY ITEM_ID
```

Comment: I want them in a separate column so I can substract them

Answer (score 0):

You want conditional aggregation, i.e. case expressions in the aggregation function:

```
SELECT
  item_id,
  SUM(quantity) AS total,
  SUM(CASE WHEN type = 'IN' THEN quantity ELSE 0 END) AS in,
  SUM(CASE WHEN type = 'OUT' THEN quantity ELSE 0 END) AS out
FROM mytable
GROUP BY item_id
ORDER BY item_id;
```

Another option would be to join the query results:

```
SELECT *
FROM ( <first query here> ) q1
JOIN ( <second query here> ) q2 USING (item_id);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do as using the below queries with OR condition for type / You can use IN condition to get in a single result.
Both will do the same work, just the query condition is different.

**Using OR condition:**

```
  SELECT ITEM_ID, TYPE , SUM(QUANTITY) AS TYPE_SUM

  WHERE TYPE = "OUT" OR TYPE = "IN"

  GROUP BY ITEM_ID, TYPE
```

If we are using the same column then we can use OR condition to fetch the data.

**Using IN Condition**

```
  SELECT ITEM_ID,TYPE , SUM(QUANTITY) AS TYPE_SUM

  WHERE TYPE IN ("OUT", "IN")

  GROUP BY ITEM_ID,TYPE
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use `COUNT` and `IF`

```
SELECT 
    ITEM_ID, 
    COUNT(IF(TYPE='IN',1,0)) AS IN_QUANTITY, 
    COUNT(IF(TYPE='OUT',1,0)) AS OUT_QUANTITY
WHERE TYPE IN ('OUT','IN')
GROUP BY ITEM_ID
```